# How to get event triggered for Shopify recurring charges?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I did the API calls for the recurring charges for the app I created in the shopify with required parameters and got redirected to the given `return_url` after the user's response and the response details were saved into the database along with the `charge_id`.

What I required is in the upcoming months if the user's debit/credit card doesn't have enough balance to pay for the recurring charge or the payment failed, how can I know that the subscription is failed in the next month? I just want to update it in the database to pause my service untill the payment gets success.

Is there any webhooks or event triggered in such a case or does it call the same API that I have given as `return_url` during the initial recurring charge? 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not deal with billing directly like that. Shopify deals with collecting the money. If the merchant's credit card fails, they are locked out of using their Shopify store anyway, so you do not have to shut down their use of your App. If you try and make API calls you'll get a 400 series error about frozen account, and thus even if they could get into your App, they could do nothing.

So you do not really have to write any code for any of this. Instead, maybe try focus on writing actual App code and get past the payment part. Having complex payment logic will only hold you back.

Comment: This make sense. Thanks David. Suppose after the next month's subscription should I use the same `charge_id` as previous to get the subscription of the current month or have unique `charge_id` in each month?

Comment: You examine your subscriptions with a GET to the endpoint RecurringApplicationCharge. You do not deal with charge_id or any other aspect of the subscription unless you delete it and create a new one.